# WPF Centering Elements On Canvas Via Code

Tags: wpf, canvas, center

I found this resource [Centering On Canvas](http://blogorama.nerdworks.in/entry-CenteringelementsonacanvasinWP.aspx). But the problem is I cannot use the same thing via C# because the canvas left and top values are returning zero and throwing an exception.Not always will I place elements on canvas via xaml, so how can I use C# to implement this. Please help.

```
<Canvas.Left>
 <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MidValue}"
               ConverterParameter="1">
   <Binding ElementName="cnvMain2"
            Path="ActualWidth" />
   <Binding ElementName="tbSize2"
            Path="ActualWidth" />
 </MultiBinding>
</Canvas.Left>
<Canvas.Top>
 <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MidValue}"
               ConverterParameter="7">
   <Binding ElementName="cnvMain2"
            Path="ActualHeight" />
   <Binding ElementName="tbSize2"
            Path="ActualHeight" />
 </MultiBinding>
</Canvas.Top>
```

Comment: Please post meaningful xaml with all referred elements and resources in place or even better just stripped down example of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I'll second Stanislav. What are trying to center where?

Comment: I'm trying to center a rectangle in this case(matter of fact any object).

Comment: I'm really stuck. I want to learn how to write the same code as above in C# for centering a rectangle using the midvalue resource. Please help....

Answer (score 0):

Although the post is quite old I just made use of the above code and wanted to share my solution in case anyone else needs it:

```
public MainWindow()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  this.SizeChanged += new SizeChangedEventHandler(MainWindow_SizeChanged);
}

void MainWindow_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
  var midValueConverter = new MidValueConverter();

  double left = (double)midValueConverter.Convert(new object[] { cnvMain2.ActualWidth, tbSize2.ActualWidth }, typeof(double), null, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);
  Canvas.SetLeft(tbSize2, left);

  double top = (double)midValueConverter.Convert(new object[] { cnvMain2.ActualHeight, tbSize2.ActualHeight }, typeof(double), null, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);
  Canvas.SetTop(tbSize2, top);

}
```